# Comments screen in backend, how to disable Quick Edit | Edit | History | Spam | for non admins

Tags: comments, spam, quick-edit, trash

I'm trying to adjust the comments screen for non admins to my project.
Right now I'd like to disable

**Quick Edit | Edit | History | Spam**

under any comment left for any post created by the user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done filtering the `*_row_actions`.
For the Comments screen <sup>(`/wp-admin/edit-comments.php`)</sup> this is the hook:

```
add_filter( 'comment_row_actions', 'comments_row_wpse_92313', 15, 2 );

function comments_row_wpse_92313( $actions, $comment )
{
    if( !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        unset( $actions['quickedit'], $actions['edit'], $actions['spam'] );

    return $actions;
}
```

I cannot see a `History` option, maybe it's included by some plugin (?). It's a matter of adding it to the `unset` list.
These are the [default actions in the core files](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php#L388):

```
$actions = array(
    'approve' => '', 
    'unapprove' => '',
    'reply' => '',
    'quickedit' => '',
    'edit' => '',
    'spam' => '', 
    'unspam' => '',
    'trash' => '', 
    'untrash' => '', 
    'delete' => ''
);
```